# python , pyxelでのエラーについて

Tags: python

あるYouTubeの動画を参考にpyxelを使用してテトリスを作ろうとしていたところ、エラーが出ました。解決策があれば教えてください。よろしくお願いします。
以下は使用したコードとエラーです。

実行環境はwindows11、python3.9.0、pyxel1.6.9、jupyter notebookで実行

```
from random import randint
import pyxel

TILE_SIZE = 8
MAP_WIDTH = 14
MAP_HEIGHT = 25
WAIT = 60

        
class Tetris:
    def __init__(self):
        self.mGameOver = False
        self.mNext = randint(0,6)
        self.mX = 0
        self.mY = 0
        self.mA = 0
        self.mT = 0
        self.mWait = 0
    
        pyxel.init(MAP_WIDTH*TILE_SIZE , 
                   MAP_HEIGHT*TILE_SIZE ,fps = 10)
        pyxel.load('tetris.pyxres')
    
        self.next()
    
        pyxel.run(self.update , self.draw)
    
    def update(self):
        pass

    def draw(self):
        pyxel.bltm(0,0,0,0,0,MAP_WIDTH,MAP_HEIGHT)
      
    
    def put(self,x,y,t,a,s,test):
        for j in range(4):
            for i in range(4):
                p = [i,3-j,3-i,j]
                q = [j,i,3-j,3-i]
                if pyxel.tilemap(0).get(16+t*4+p[a],q[a]) == 7:
                continue
                
                v=t
                if s == False:
                v=7
                elif pyxel.tilemap(0).get(x+i , y+j) != 7:
                    return False
                if test == False:
                    pyxel.tilemap(0).set(x+i , y+j , v)
                
        return True

    def next(self):
        self.mX = 5
        self.mY = 2
        self.mT = self.mNext
        self.mWait = WAIT
    
        self.mA = 0
        if pyxel.btn(pyxel.KEY_X):
            self.mA = 3
        if pyxel.btn(pyxel.KEY_Z):
            self.mA = 1
    
        if self.put(self.mX , self.mY , self.mT , self.mA , True , False) == False:
            self.mGameOver = True
    
        self.put(5,-1,self.mNext,0,False,False)
        self.mNext = randint(0,6)
        self.put(5,-1,self.mNext,0,True,False)
    
Tetris()
```

**エラーメッセージ**

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-c5ae4bd3c03b> in <module>
     69         self.put(5,-1,self.mNext,0,True,False)
     70 
---> 71 Tetris()

<ipython-input-1-c5ae4bd3c03b> in __init__(self)
     21         pyxel.load('tetris.pyxres')
     22 
---> 23         self.next()
     24 
     25         pyxel.run(self.update , self.draw)

<ipython-input-1-c5ae4bd3c03b> in next(self)
     62             self.mA = 1
     63 
---> 64         if self.put(self.mX , self.mY , self.mT , self.mA , True , False) == False:
     65             self.mGameOver = True
     66 

<ipython-input-1-c5ae4bd3c03b> in put(self, x, y, t, a, s, test)
     37                 p = [i,3-j,3-i,j]
     38                 q = [j,i,3-j,3-i]
---> 39                 if pyxel.tilemap(0).get(16+t*4+p[a],q[a]) == 7:
     40                     continue
     41 

AttributeError: 'builtins.Tilemap' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Comment: 元にした動画はこれでしょうか [Python Pyxel でテトリスを作ってみた【プログラミング解説】](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VyprhrtjS2A) さらにその流用元 [Python Pyxel でレトロなスネークゲームを作ってみた【プログラミング解説】](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6g7D1l6A9T8) そしてマルチポスト先 [pyxelでのエラーについて](https://teratail.com/questions/0msgq3ettnppfx) でpyxelの版数による違い [【pyxel 1.5】Pyxel Editor使用方法まとめ](https://note.com/koide_mizu1433/n/n289cf5c5c785) についての紹介コメントが付いています。あと作者による会員制掲示板があるようなので、その会員になって質問してみるのも手かもしれません。[ゲームプログラミング](http://www.free.netgamers.jp/prog/)

Comment: 当サイトは日本語でのやり取りをメインにしているので、英語の併記は不要です。

Comment: マルチポスト先でコメントが付いていますが、ドキュメントの[タイルマップクラス](https://github.com/kitao/pyxel/blob/main/doc/README.ja.md#%E3%82%BF%E3%82%A4%E3%83%AB%E3%83%9E%E3%83%83%E3%83%97%E3%82%AF%E3%83%A9%E3%82%B9) を見ると`get()`メソッドは無くて`pget()`メソッドがあります。動画の投稿日2020/01/19あたりだとpyxelの版数は`1.2.10`でしょうから[Release history](https://pypi.org/project/pyxel/#history)、pyxelの版数をそこまで下げるか、`get()`を`pget()`に変えてみるか、いずれかを試してみてはどうでしょう？